# Can't change img on Carousel with translateX()

Tags: carousel

The following is my code. I wished to make a Carousel, but I can't change the img when i click the next or prev button.  (super frustrated..

Hope someone can help me with what issue am i facing. Thank you so much in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Carousel</title>
  <style>
    body {
      position: relative;
    }

    .container {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      width: 700px;
      justify-content: space-around;
      margin: auto;
      /* border: 1px solid black; */
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .slider {
      width: 550px;
      height: 300px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slides {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      /* transform: translateX(-1100px); */
    }

    .slide {
      min-width: 550px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }

    .button {
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 25px;
      width: 25px;
    }

    .next {
      background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
      border: none;
      color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
    }

    .prev {
      border: none;
      background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
      color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
      order: -1;
    }

    button:hover {
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }

    .light {
      background-color: black;
    }

    .pagination {
      list-style: none;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: 5px;
      height: 8px;
      width: 15px;
    }

    .pagination-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slides">
        <img class="slide" src="https://www.kpopn.com/upload/fa639a8e1ae64ce8f2c0.jpg" alt="Twice Fancy Cover"></img>
        <img class="slide" src="https://cdn1.wishnote.tw/200/2018/04/24/200_91441_1524554375.jpeg"
          alt="Twice What is Love MV"></img>
        <img class="slide" src="https://img.ltn.com.tw/Upload/ent/page/800/2021/11/06/phpqJ2lIs.jpg"
          alt="Twice Formula of Love Cover"></img>
        <img class="slide" src="https://static.popdaily.com.tw/u/202109/4b573e45-9586-41e7-bd5d-c391bbfb2a60.jpg"
          alt="Twice The Feels Cover"></img>
        <img class="slide" src="https://thebiaslistcom.files.wordpress.com/2024/02/twice-i-got-you.jpeg"
          alt="Twice I Got You Cover"></img>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="prev button" onclick="prevslide()">&#10094</button>
    <button class="next button" onclick="nextslide()">&#10095</button>
    <ul class="pagination-container">
      <li class="pagination"></li>
      <li class="pagination"></li>
      <li class="pagination"></li>
      <li class="pagination"></li>
      <li class="pagination"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <script>
    let slides = document.querySelector('.slides')
    let slider= document.querySelector('.slider')
    let index = 0
    let move = 550
    let pagination = document.querySelectorAll('.pagination')
    let img = document.querySelectorAll('img')
    let moveRange = move * index

    function currentslide() {
      index = 0
      changePagination()
    }
    currentslide()

    function nextslide() {
      index++;
      if (index >= img.length) {
        index = 0
      }
      slides.style.transform = `translateX(-${moveRange}px);`
      changePagination()
    }

    function prevslide() {
      index--;
      if (index < 0) {
        index = img.length - 1
      }
      slides.style.transform = `translateX(${moveRange}px);`
      changePagination()
    }

    let timer = setInterval(nextslide, 5000)

    slides.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
      clearInterval(timer)
    })

    slides.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
      timer = setInterval(nextslide, 5000)
    }
    )

    function changePagination() {
      pagination.forEach((pag, pagindex) => {
        if (pagindex === index) {
          pag.classList.add('light')
        }
        else {
          pag.classList.remove('light')
        }
      })
    }

    pagination.forEach((pag, pagindex) => {
      pag.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        pagination.forEach((p, Index) => {
          if (Index !== pagindex) {
            p.classList.remove('light')
          } else {
            p.classList.add('light')
            clearInterval(timer)
          }
        })
      })
      pag.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        timer = setInterval(nextslide, 5000)
      });
    })

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I use transform: translateX() on the slider, but it didn't work.
I should be able to click the next or previous button and change the picture with transition.